# How to blur everything except 2 nodes. Spritekit (Swift)

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, blur

I'd like to blur the background of my game when

```
self.view?.scene?.paused = true
```

But the the button and the paused label (both SKSpriteNode's) should not be blur. they all have different Z-index values.
The scene is paused when the button node is pressed and resumed when the button is pressed again.

I cant find a way to achieve this in Swift.
i found some suggestions that use SKEffectNode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic steps...

1. Create an SKEffectsNode
2. Create a CIGaussianBlur CIFilter
3. Assign the filter to the effects node
4. Add nodes to the effects node (child nodes will be blurred)

and example code in Swift...

```
// Create an effects node with a gaussian blur filter
let effectsNode = SKEffectNode()
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
// Set the blur amount. Adjust this to achieve the desired effect
let blurAmount = 10.0
filter?.setValue(blurAmount, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

effectsNode.filter = filter
effectsNode.position = self.view!.center
effectsNode.blendMode = .alpha

// Create a sprite
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

// Add the sprite to the effects node. Nodes added to the effects node
// will be blurred
effectsNode.addChild(sprite)
// Add the effects node to the scene
self.addChild(effectsNode)

// Create another sprite
let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
sprite2.position = self.view!.center
sprite2.size = CGSize(width:64, height:64);
sprite2.zPosition = 100

// Add the sprite to the scene. Nodes added to the scene won't be blurred
self.addChild(sprite2)
```

Comment: How do I unblur them? Would I just remove the `effectsNode`, or would I remove all of its children?

Comment: Also, the line `filter.setValue(blurAmount, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)` is throwing up an error saying **"Sending float to parameter of incompatible type 'id'"**. If it matters at all, I converted this code to objective-c.

Comment: @ChristianKRider here's an obj-c version of that statement: `[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0] forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];`. To unblur the sprites, you can either remove them from the effects node and then add them to the scene or set `effectsNode.filter = nil;`

Comment: @ChristianKRider you can also set `effectsNode.shouldEnableEffects = NO;` to unblur the sprites.

Comment: @0x121E OK, thank you for that! I ended up not needing it, so you don't have to continue helping me out. But if I ever need it again, I'll come back here.